# What is the difference between add and put in indexeddb?

Tags: indexeddb

I am just starting to use indexeddb and transforming Web SQL.

I tried to use add and put to add some data in data store. I could not really see what is/are the difference/s of using these two functions.

I think I have to know the difference so I could use them appropriately.

Thanks forward

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic

Comment: Can you tell me why is it off topic? It is a concrete question

Comment: It is a good question because if you do not setup error handling correctly it is not immediately obvious that add fails when the key already exists.  It is also not clear that put will also add.

Answer (score 47):

The difference between add and put is same as in any API.

If you try to insert an element with key that already exist using the `put` function it will trigger and update of the existing element, however if you use the `add` function and element with same id exist you will get an error with the following message: "Key already exists in the object store."

Comment: Absolutely agree, I think it is worth to mention "put" not only update but also can add value if the given key does not exist.

Comment: Is there any reason for using add, if put can do both creating and updating a record?

Comment: @Y.Yoshii It can be useful if you want to do safe addition - adding without replacing. Additional logic to check whether a key already exists won't have to be written, `add()` will do that for you.